# How to convert string to char* using stringstream?

Tags: c++, string, char, stringstream

I have a function like this:

```
template <typename T>
void parse_to_T(const std::string& str, T* result) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    ss >> *result;
}
```

this function is mean to convert the string to the specified type.

it is work to parse the string to int, float or char.

```
parse_to_T<int>(...);
parse_to_T<float>(...);
parse_to_T<char>(...);
```

but when meet char*, segment fault ...

I use the function like this:

```
int int_val;
string m = "1";
parse_to_T<int>(m, &int_val); // works
char* str_val = NULL;
parse_to_T<char*>(m, &str_val); // segmentfault
```

How to imply this function to make it work?

(convert the string to specified type like int, double, char, char*)?

Hey, I don't know how to explain my use case, but I will try:

To simple, the question is, given a file, for each line, data may have these types :

- int
- float
- char
- char*
- an array T[num] (T is int, float, char or char*, or any build_in type.)

imple a parse function to parse this file.

and this problem is an exam ...

---

thanks and I found the error now.

```
char* str_val = NULL;
parse_to_T<char*>(m, &str_val); // segmentfault;
char* str_val;
parse_to_T<char*>(m, &str_val); // segmentfault;
char* str_val = new char[256];
parse_to_T<char*>(m, &str_val); // works !!
```

then the error is I didn't allocate memory to the ptr...

Comment: You're dereferencing an uninitialized pointer

Comment: I don't suppose you would find functions like the [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) and [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) families more appealing? It seems to me you're trying to reinvent a wheel here.

Comment: @Tas sorry.. I just forget to type it to the question.

Comment: @WhozCraig I really know this function works. But my problem is to imple a   common  function to convert it to specified type..........

Comment: Your question really just doesn't make any sense. Why would you want to convert a string to a char* using stringstream? What possible use case could there be for that?

Comment: Don't use `char*`.

Comment: Replace `char* str_val = NULL;` with `char* str_val;`. Or just use `char* str_val = m.c_str();`

Comment: @n.m. what should I use ?

Comment: @ETech  Replace char* str_val = NULL with char* str_val;        it doesn't work, still segmentfault.

Comment: @ETech: No, and no. The first is undefined behavior, the second will not compile.

Comment: Use std::string, obviously.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I modified my question and explain it , does it make sense now ?

Comment: @n.m. convert a string to string ?  ..but that's not what I wan't ... I wanna this function support convert string to char* ...

Comment: You are trying to use char * pointer without any memory allocation and/or size definition. It seems that you wish to make universal transformer for all types. So, before using char * - allocate memory for m characters or use char[] array. And of course - it shall remove universal effect.

Comment: Correct, you don't want to convert a string to a string. You don't need the function supporting types you don't use, so just don't use `char*` and don't worry about the function not supporting it.

Comment: Brute forcing this all into one function is possible, but problematic. You could make a specialization that handles `char *` in a much more intelligent manner, but I join the crowd wondering why bother?

Comment: @ETech yeah, I found the error now, thanks !!!

Comment: @李浩然 Nope, still completely baffled. A `char *` is a C++ pointer type. A pointer can't possibly be stored in a file and be useful since it's only meaningful inside a process. A file can have strings in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This segfault is because `stringstream` does not allocate memory to hold the result of the operation when extracting values into a `char*` array.  It tries to put the values into the memory pointed at by the lhs operand.  You must allocate memory yourself.

Here is a simple example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void parse_to_T(const std::string& str, T* result) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << str;
    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;
    ss >> *result;
    std::cout << *result << std::endl;
}

int main() {
   char* buffer = new char[256];
   /* Don't do this in real code. If the input is larger than
      the size of the buffer it will end very, very badly.
      always have a way of allocating the correct amount
      of memory.
   */
   int int_val;
   std::string m = "1";
   parse_to_T<int>(m, &int_val);
   char* str_val = NULL;
   parse_to_T<char*>(m, &buffer);
   delete[] buffer;
   return 0;
}
```

You could include a template specialization for the `char*` datatype that does the allocation based on the amount of data in the stream (calling `stringstream.str().size()` should work) but the user would have to free the returned memory.

Comment: Be careful with fixed-lengths arrays: if input is larger then it will overflow or you may have a security issue. Last is true even if the specification of input states a maximum length, it can always be compromised.

Comment: No need for `new`. Allocate buffer as a temporary and let the compiler deal with it.

Comment: There's also no need for the both insertion and extraction. `std::istringstream ss(str);` , then the extraction, should be all that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

First, your destination variable `str_val` has no allocated memory, so it is normal you have a segmentation fault.

On the other hand, it would be better if you use `std::string` instead. If you need the raw pointer `const char*` then you can use [`std::string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) for so. If you have to modify it then just create a copy.